# Model validation and redirect in Partial Views in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I have multiple partial views in one page, when there is a *submit* on one partial view, and there is a model level validation on it, I need to stay in the same Page.

Using the below code

```
 return PartialView(<modelname>)
```

Redirects to a new page and not to the same parent page where the request came from.

Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: Look at ajax. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667274/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Razorengine, then you could try this code

@Html.Partial("ViewName", ModelName)

In the Partial view you can use Ajax.BeginForm to call your controller and model which will be used on hit of submit button