# Unable to display validation in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the code from the below link. It works fine . But though there are validation errors, and ValidationSummary(true/false) is enabled, I am not able to see the validation message.

[ASP.NET MVC Partial view ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667274/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-ajax-post)

As a work around ,When I try to display error message explicitly using the below code, it still does not display .When in debug mode, the ModelState has the error message , but it does not display .

```
 <div>
 @{
    foreach (var i in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {

        <ol>
            @{
                if(i.Errors != null && i.Errors.Count>0)
               {
                   var error = i.Errors[0];
                  <li>error.ErrorMessage</li> 
                }
              }
         </ol> 
       }
   }
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.ValidationMessage` html helper to display property-level validation message in your partial view.

Comment: I am using this code on the properties     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.UserName)