# MVC RenderAction return only renders partial part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have this contact form which I want to use on two pages (two views) in MVC 5.x (razor viewengine) So I have put the form in an partialview called _Contact and I have read that RenderAction is the best approach if you do not have the required data for the partialview in your model and if it is more standalone (seperate from the rest of the view)

So I call it like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SendMail", "Uk");}
```

My Uk controller has these two methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult SendMail()
{
    return PartialView("_Contact");
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SendMail(FormCollection fc)
{
    // send mail using values out of the form (sorry did not feel like building a complete model for it
    ViewBag.Succeed = true;
    // if smtpclient could not reach server etc. it returns false
    return PartialView("_Contact");
}
```

it all works, but the `PartialView` is only rendered, not on the placeholder where i call the `RenderAction`. It works all great, but after the post it just displays the partial view and not the "parent view" and the shared layout view etc. I hope that I made myself clear. Please let me know if I need to add more info.

This is the `BeginForm` from my shared view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Uk", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Maybe because you're returning a `PartialView` in the case of GET or POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work as expected for your current code, because when you post the form, it returns `Partial View` not complete `View`. If you want to get only partial view then you have to submit your form via Ajax.

In ajax's success handler you will get HTML of your partial view and that you can put in a DIV tag of partial view container.

This link will give you a better idea about  Posting Partial View via Ajax.

[ASP.NET MVC Partial view ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667274/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-ajax-post)