# MVC 5 Routing using without reloading the entire page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I new to MVC 5, trying to develop a website using MVC 5 with routing built-in.
I just developed a master layout and inside that I am loading another layout with @RenderSection("WorkArea"), this one is for all sub pages which renders inside the main layout(parent layout). but whenever I try to load the sub layout the entire page gets reloaded, is there any way to load the sub pages only not the entire one again and again.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are talking about well known technology: `AJAX`

Comment: but I when I am using ActionLink to route to a particular page and then loads it inside the master page. how does it work. Can I have an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AJAX` with mvc partial view

Here are some links for how to implement it

[How can i load Partial view inside the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295835/how-can-i-load-partial-view-inside-the-view)

[ASP.NET MVC Partial view ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667274/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-ajax-post)

[Render Partial View Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)